# WebSocket: best solution for back-end

Tags: java, javascript, websocket, backend

Evented web apps are an hot topics these days, but it appears there is not a unique solution for that. Especially for the back-end side, independently from the programming language.

I open this topics to discuss about the various solutions offered to the community.

I tried Atmosphere, but the experience was a bit frustrating.
I spend a lot of time playing with this framework and I ended up that it was not completely developer-friendly. First of all is a maven-based project: in addition to the documentation a developer has to learn (or at least to know) how maven works and what's a pom.xml is.
Concepts looks easy, but it's plenty of java annotations, that in my opinion tends the make things too complex. The strength of this framework is that is able to decide and use the protocols supported by the client.

From what I have read node.js appears to be the more developer-friendly.
What do you think about these technologies?

Comment: what is "easy" for you is largely going to depend on what technologies you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend node.js.

It's coded in javascript, and I personally really like being able to stick to web languages.

Also, you can use socket.io, which implements websockets using node.js.

Comment: I also think that most of the people here would choose node.js for a websocket solution.

I've just discovered this webbit: http://thechangelog.com/webbit-a-java-event-based-websocket-and-http-server/: a server-side java websocket server. Even though it does not implement fall-back protocols, I think it could be a valid java alternative.

Answer (score 6):

I am the project leader of [CometD](http://cometd.org), which is a web messaging framework that is transport agnostic (websocket with fallback to http) and ships a lot of features like message acknowledgement and [clustering](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/java_oort.html) and many others.

CometD is also based on Maven, but its artifacts can be consumed with any other build system you already have (Ant, Ivy, Gradle, etc.).

[CometD concepts](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/concepts.html) are pretty simple, and you can write services that are either [annotated](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/java_server.html#java_server_services_annotated_server_side) or [use inheritance](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/java_server.html#java_server_services_inherited).

CometD scalability is awesome: a single server in our load testing was able to handle 200k websocket clients, and other people reached even more (https://twitter.com/myBuzzNight/status/388024046027161600).

The CometD learning curve is quite low, from the reports I have.
One guy setup [e-chat.co](http://www.e-chat.co/) in few days.

You can setup a skeleton CometD project with a [one liner](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/primer.html) or even use a pre-made skeleton project used by the [CometD tutorials](http://docs.cometd.org/tutorials).

JavaScript being the language it is, you'll probably find that if your project grows beyond a certain size you want to stay with a statically typed language like Java for its refactorings, tools, IDEs, etc., not to mention the tools that are available for the JVM for monitoring/management, etc.

The scalability of the JVM in multithreaded scenarios like server-side event-driven applications is well known.

Like other solutions, CometD is [backed by a company](http://webtide.com) in case you need professional support.